# ActionScript ProgressBar ProgressBarMode.EVENT

Tags: events, actionscript, progress-bar

im new to flash and actionscript.

the page in question can be seen [here](http://www.guygar.com).

my AS code:

```
import fl.video.*;
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
import fl.controls.ProgressBarMode;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import fl.events.ComponentEvent;

// FLVplayback control
splashVid.visible = false;

progressBar.mode = ProgressBarMode.EVENT;
progressBar.indeterminate = false;
progressBar.source = splashVid;

progressBar.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, doSwitch);
progressBar.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    iLabel.text = Math.round(event.bytesLoaded).toString();
}

function doSwitch(e:Event):void
{
    iLabel.text = "loaded";
}
```

the issue is although progressHandler callback works properly (ProgressEvent.PROGRESS). the doSwitch callback never fires (Event.COMPLETE).

could you kindly explain the error in my approach?

OBJECTIVE: i am trying to load a mp4 of a fixed size and then use the COMPLETE event to render controls of the movie clip.

thank you.

EDIT: the COMPLETE event does fire now after test but it fires after the entire clip has been played. how would i go about firing event.complete once the video file has been loaded but not played? thank you.

EDIT: i could do a comparison between bytesloaded and totalbytes in progressHandler... but the issue there is the progress animation never completes fully and i would like to display a full progressbar before switching display settings.

EDIT: the progressbar completes the loading animation if i do not hide it once the complete file has been loaded so that takes care of my issue.

HOWEVER: i am still open to tips regarding if there is a better way of doing this using some sort of COMPLETE event that fires once the source mp4 file has completely been downloaded. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an FLVPlayer

Not sure about your naming conventions but if I read the code correctly splashVid is the instance name of your FLVplayer.
so what you need to do is listen to the player not the progress bar.
As per the [DOCS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#event%3aready)

```
splashVid.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, doSwitch);
```

If this is not correct you need to remove all your edits and post 1 question and more specifics about your app.

Comment: VideoEvent.READY informs of metadata like duration and fires at the begging of the load and not when the entire clip is ready/has been downloaded.